# Zooming an image using moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I am new to stakoverflow and I was hoping to get some help with a python code.

I've written a code that transforms an image from a folder into a 5-second video. The concept involves taking a single image and gradually zooming in as it plays. However, I've encountered an issue where the videos generated initially have black bars around the image. These black bars disappear as the image progressively zooms in and fills the screen. My intention was for the image to occupy the entire screen right from the beginning of the video and then zoom in further from that point onward. I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this specific effect. Can anyone help?

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import moviepy.editor as mp

def create_zooming_video(image_path, output_path, duration=5, resolution=(1080, 1920)):
    img = mp.ImageClip(image_path)
    
    # Calculate the initial and final zoom scales
    initial_zoom = 1.0
    final_zoom = 1.5
    
    # Calculate the zooming scale for each frame
    zoom_scales = np.linspace(initial_zoom, final_zoom, int(duration * 30))  # 30 frames per second
    
    # Calculate the dimensions for the cropped image
    cropped_width = resolution[0]
    cropped_height = int(resolution[0] * (img.size[1] / img.size[0]))
    
    # Resize the image to fit the cropped dimensions
    img = img.resize((cropped_width, cropped_height))
    
    # Create a list to hold each frame of the zooming animation
    zooming_frames = []
    for scale in zoom_scales:
        frame = img.resize(scale)
        frame = frame.set_position(("center", "center"))
        frame = frame.set_duration(1 / 30)  # Each frame lasts 1/30 seconds
        zooming_frames.append(frame)
    
    # Create the zooming animation clip
    zooming_clip = mp.concatenate_videoclips(zooming_frames, method="compose")
    
    # Calculate position to keep the zoomed image centered
    position = ("center", "center")
    
    zooming_clip = zooming_clip.set_position(position)
    zooming_clip = zooming_clip.set_duration(duration)
    zooming_clip = zooming_clip.set_fps(30)
    
    zooming_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec="libx264")

def main():
    output_folder = "output_videos"
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    png_files = glob.glob("*.png")

    for png_file in png_files:
        filename_without_extension = os.path.splitext(png_file)[0]
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{filename_without_extension}.mp4")
        create_zooming_video(png_file, output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm attempting to make the image begin at 100% scale within the video and then progressively zoom in. It's ok for parts of the image to be outside the video's boundaries by the end of the zooming process.